# Two ways of writing the Fourier transform of the mod function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I feel there are two ways of writing the Fourier transform of $\vert x \vert$ and they are,

- that it is $\pm i \sqrt{2\pi} \delta'(t)$ for $x \geq0$ or $<0$
- that it is $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{1}{t^2}$

(for frequency $t$)

What is the relationship between these two above expressions? 
Its not clear that they are the same!

Comment: You are confusing a few things here. What is true is that $|x|''=2\delta$ (not the other way around), so (up to constants) $t^2\widehat{|x|}=1$, which superficially might seem to imply your second formula, but that's not really true because $\widehat{|x|}$ will not be function, so there will be a regularization near $t=0$ ($1/t^2$ as a function is not a tempered distribution).

Comment: So for $t \neq 0$ are the two expressions supposed to be equivalent? Could you give a reference which explains how to define the Fourier Transform of $\vert x \vert$ for all $t$?

Comment: $|x|$ is a tempered distribution, hence its Fourier transform is also a tempered distribution, and it is well-defined and unique

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $|x|=x=\text{ramp}(x)$ for $x>0$, then $|x|=\text{ramp}(x)+\text{ramp}(-x)$.

Since $$\mathcal{F}\{f(-x)\}=F(-\omega)$$
we have $$\mathcal{F}\{|x|\}=\mathcal{F}\{\text{ramp}(x)+\text{ramp}(-x)\}=G(\omega)+G(-\omega)$$
where $G(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{\text{ramp}(x)\}=j\pi\delta'(\omega)-\frac{1}{\omega^2}$

Hence,
$$\mathcal{F}\{|x|\}=-\frac{2}{\omega^2}=-\frac{1}{2\pi^2f^2}$$

Comment: with $f(x) = |x|$, $f'(x) = \text{sign}(x), f''(x) =2 \delta(x)$, and $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ (where $\text{sign}(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\text{sign}(x)+\text{sign}(-x)}{2}$) so that $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi) = \frac{\mathcal{F}\{f''\}(\xi)}{(2i\pi \xi)^2} = \frac{2}{(2i\pi \xi)^2} =  \frac{-1}{2\pi^2 \xi^2}$

Comment: Indeed, this was the first thing I was about to write. But I had answered another question from gradstudent with FT of ramp function. So I thought they could be related...

Comment: ok it makes sense. I thought you wanted to avoid $f''(x) = 2 \delta(x)$, but since $|x|$ is essentially a (tempered) distribution, I don't think we can really avoid the (tempered) distribution theory anyway.

Comment: or maybe we can say $\mathcal{F}\{ramp(x)\}(\xi)$ is the limit when $Re(s) \to 0$ of the Laplace transform, and $\int_0^\infty x e^{-sx} dx$ is easy to compute, but for the $|x| 1_{x < 0}$ part we'll have a problem

Comment: This possibly cannot be the whole answer, right? We would need to have a definition of what is the Fourier Transform of $mod(x)$ at $0$ frequency.

Comment: @gradstudent This is the final answer, i.e. the FT of $|x|$. I think you were looking for the FT of $|x|$ in the question right?

Comment: What is the Fourier Transform value at $f=0$? There has to be some distributional answer for that. Riight?