# Fourier transform of absolute values

Tags: fourier-transform

Is the following statement true? $$\int_{-2}^2 (2-|x|)e^{-iwx}\ dx=\int_{-2}^0 (x+2)e^{-iwx}\ dx + \int_0^2 (2-x)e^{-iwx}\ dx$$
This seems logical to me, but it does not give me the correct answer. Why is this the case and how do you properly evaluate such integral?

Comment: Yes it's true, but what is this "correct answer"?

Comment: Maybe you find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1921090/350875) useful.